# Android Studio Emulator Stops my App from Showing

Tags: android-studio

I tried running my emulator and it gave me a message saying that my app failed to work. I then looked in the LogChat in Android Studio and found these error messages. I am new to android studio and I'm not sure what to do to make this app work on the emulator and get rid of these errors.

I have tried to run the emulator from Android Studio and this is the error

```
07-18 14:52:16.437 3457-3457/tech.tab.testtab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tech.tab.testtab, PID: 3457
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:396)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:391)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:107)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Normally, these errors don't show up

Comment: As the error states, this is a null pointer exception.
By looking at the context, it is probably caused by a bad layout, maybe something that is not there,  or maybe a wrong cast.
Could you paste some of the layout file, along with the code where you are using it, that would help

Comment: here's the code for One of my layouts.                 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lstUserPayed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: public class payedserviceFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    public payedserviceFragment() {
        //does nothing for now
    }

Comment: public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,

Comment: @Nullable ViewGroup container,

Comment: @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

Comment: view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.

Comment: payedservice_fragment,container,false);

Comment: return view; }}

Comment: I have all my imports

Comment: Joshua: You can add your formatted code by editing the question, that way is more  readable than adding comments with single lines of code

Comment: Okay, I'll upload the project to Github and post the link on here for anyone to contribute to the project file

Comment: Here is the link to the repo on Github. Please take a look at it and contribute to the code and please help me understand.https://github.com/KarltonSen/TestTab

Comment: Please check your repo, the code is not there. You forgot to upload the src files

Comment: I just updated it. Look for TestTab-two. https://github.com/KarltonSen/TestTab

Comment: Joshua, look at my answer below. Do not forget to mark the answer as coorect if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now that the repo is in place, this is really easy to fix, just go to your viewPagerAdapter, and change the null in the getItem method:

[image]

And then.....magic!

[image]

You are returning a null fragment from your adapter, that's all

Comment: This is the best answer. Do you make the change to the repo on Github?

Comment: You're welcome, and No, Joshua, I did not change your repository.  When something like this occurs to me, I usually like to make the changes myself in order to fully understand what needs to be changed to resolve the problem. Best wishes for you and your android development path!

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it is clear that your code is trying to operate on null object and throws **NullPointerException in BackStackRecord.java at line 396**. Check that line and give your variable default value "0" or whatever that does not affect your result. Try running the code. It should work. Or Please provide the snippet of the code for review.

Comment: this is what line 396 shows                                                                                   
       public FragmentTransaction setBreadCrumbTitle(int res) {
        this.mBreadCrumbTitleRes = res;
        this.mBreadCrumbTitleText = null;
        return this;
    }

Comment: make sure, the value of "res" is not null when passing it as an argument in the line 396. Place a breakpoint and check it out by debugging it. Also make sure that return type "this" is not being null while returning.

Comment: I tried that, however, here is the link to the full project file on Github. Please download and try it out and see if it works for you. Please help out!! https://github.com/KarltonSen/TestTab